# How can I do this trick with css and/or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<img src="..." />

// other stuff 

<div id="image">
<a href="" > bla bla bla </a>
<a href="" > ble ble ble </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image a:hover{color:green;}
```

I want this:

When the user put mouse over the image, then all the links in the div with id "image" become green ( like if the user put the mouse over the links. ).

If possible I prefer to do this with only CSS.

Comment: You really should use a class instead of an id, since technically you should only have 1 of each unique id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
img:hover + #image a {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tzpmd/

Comment: Yep this is supported in IE 8 + and most versions of open source browsers

Comment: but this works only if there isn't nothign between the image and the links :( http://jsfiddle.net/QSy9H/4/

Comment: Use the [general sibling combinator instead](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) for that situation `~` http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/QSy9H/5/

Comment: Because its the `<table>` thats a sibling of the `<img>` no the `<td>` take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/QSy9H/21/ .. you need to use `#topimg:hover ~ table #image td a` instead

Answer (score 3):

```css
img:hover + #image a{color:green;}
```

Though there are some browser quirks with respect to `:hover` used with `+`, so you'll need to do some testing and see if your supported browsers are affected.

And of course `+` will not be supported in old browsers.

---

If there's an element in between, you can use `~` instead.

```css
img:hover ~ #image a{color:green;}
```

Comment: No, some old browsers won't work. And there are some bugs in some browsers when combining `:hover` with `+`, so you should test your supported browsers.

Comment: but this works only if there isn't nothign between the image and the links :( http://jsfiddle.net/QSy9H/4

Comment: @xRobot: Right. That's what your markup example showed. You can change `+` to `~`.

Comment: @xRobot: Because `#image` isn't a sibling of the `img`. If you want it to affect *all* nested `a` elements, use `#topimg:hover ~ * a {` http://jsfiddle.net/QSy9H/27/, or make `*` specific to the sibling you want to affect.

Answer (score 1):

@xRobot, the problem with your fiddle is that you're not referencing the sibling of `#topimg`, which is the `table` not the `tr#image`. The element you are referencing is the child of the table element, and niece of the #topimg element (not sibling).

Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QSy9H/32/

... and using the examples on this page:

```
img:hover ~ table #image a{ color:green; }
```